# How do you set the start page using a server side data source

Tags: ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Using angular and a server side data source, I want to be able to load the grid at a specific page number. This will help me support the user using the back button as they go from list pages (aggrid) to detail pages.

I've discovered paginationGoToPage() but it doesn't seem to work in onGridReady, it only works if i use it on a button click. But even if I do use it, it seems like the data would have to be loaded twice, once when the grid is first rendered and then again for the particular page I want to go to.

Answer (score 1):

You can use paginationGoToPage() in onFirstDataRendered() event. Still, the data will be loaded twice, but it looks like no better option so far. It looks like this feature should be requested from AgGrid team.